# Return complex actix-web type from a function

Tags: generics, rust, actix-web

I'm trying to setup my tests for an actix-web application. I'd like to have a function that prepares the application and initializes it with `actix_web::init_service`. I'm stuck on the return type for this function. [Here's a repository](https://github.com/j-chmielewski/actix-test-generics) with simplified problem. Here's the code:

```rust
use actix_web::{App, test::init_service};


// What is the correct return type?
async fn init_app() -> () {
    let app = App::new();
    init_service(app).await
}

#[actix_web::test]
async fn test() {
    let app = init_app().await;
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> tests/tests.rs:7:5
   |
7  |     init_service(app).await
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found opaque type
   |
  ::: /home/jck/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-web-4.3.0/src/test/test_utils.rs:43:6
   |
43 | ) -> impl Service<Request, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = E>
   |      --------------------------------------------------------------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
            found opaque type `impl actix_web::dev::Service<actix_http::requests::request::Request, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = actix_web::Error>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `generics` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I tried to fill in the type suggested by the compiler, but it seems that I'm missing some types, can they be private? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Stargateur Added error message to the question.

Comment: What's wrong with the type the compiler suggests?

Comment: It says `actix_http::requests` module is private. If it's private then why does rust allow it's content to be returned from public method?

Comment: `impl actix_web::dev::Service<actix_http::Request>` should work